# git push --mirror master (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master)

Tags: git, github, large-files

I am in the process of migrating a git repository from Helix to Github.com.

Helix handles LFS automatically, but Github limits to 100mb. As a result I have to convert existing repo to LFS before pushing to Github.

I found this article: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/migrate_to_git_lfs.html

Steps I can do succesfully are:

1. git clone --mirror git@my-helix-repo-url
2. bfg --convert-to-git-lfs "Pia" --no-blob-protection my-repo.git
3. cd my-repo.git
4. git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
5. git lfs install
6. Unprotect the default branch in my github.com repo

- Here I change remote to Github from Helix

7. git push --force --mirror // ERROR!

Everything works fine until I get to step-7 which states "git push --force". As I want to push multiple branches I am using "git push --mirror --force"

This results in the following:

my-repo.git % git push --mirror --force
To github.com:MyOrganization/my-repo.git
! [remote rejected]   master (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:;MyOrganization/my-repo.git'

I was able to push with just "git push --force", but this only pushed master branch. Repos default branch in Github.com is master and there are no branch protection in place. I think it's just refusing to delete the branch because it's default :( How can I mirror push?

How can I update all of the repo's branches to large-file-storage and then push all branches to new remote? Why is it not allowing me to overwrite this one branch?

Comment: It does not make sense that `git push --force` asks the remote to *update* master but `git push --mirror --force` asks the remote to *delete* master. Either you do have a `master` locally, so that `git push --force` can push it, or you don't, so that `git push --mirror` would ask the other Git to delete it. But both cannot be true simultaneously.

Comment: @torek would I have to do this LFS transformation for each branch separately? Thanks for explaining, didn't realise --force --mirror was conflicting with each other.

Comment: I'm not saying that force and mirror conflict (in fact they don't), I'm saying that something isn't right with the description of your problem. Whether this is the right way to work with bfg and LFS, I have no idea, though.

Comment: Okay. I'm a bit confused here. I tried doing the same but with just git push --mirror, and this gave the error about too large files, so I guess this only fixes it for master branch. 

Just doing git push --force, pushed only master, which is not what I want.